# combine strings from mysql tables without extra spaces

Tags: python, mysql, regex, django, performance

I have been working on this django app. We pull a big set of tables from a California state agency, process the data and re-publish it. I have been trying to do something simple but the simple implementation is really slow and I may be thinking myself into a hole. Here is a bit of one of the tables. There are a lot of tables like this.

```
mysql> desc EXPN_CD;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| AGENT_NAMF | varchar(45)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AGENT_NAML | varchar(200)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AGENT_NAMS | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AGENT_NAMT | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AMEND_ID   | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| AMOUNT     | decimal(14,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| BAKREF_TID | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| BAL_JURIS  | varchar(40)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| BAL_NAME   | varchar(200)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| BAL_NUM    | varchar(7)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CAND_NAMF  | varchar(45)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CAND_NAML  | varchar(200)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CAND_NAMS  | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CAND_NAMT  | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CMTE_ID    | varchar(9)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CUM_OTH    | decimal(14,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CUM_YTD    | decimal(14,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DIST_NO    | varchar(3)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ENTITY_CD  | varchar(3)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EXPN_CHKNO | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EXPN_CODE  | varchar(3)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| EXPN_DATE  | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| EXPN_DSCR  | varchar(400)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| FILING_ID  | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
...
```

I am going through all of these tables. I pull out each name, the "CAND" (candidate), "AGENT", and so on, and put each reference into a row:

```
mysql> desc calaccess_campaign_browser_name;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ext_pk      | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ext_table   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ext_prefix  | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| naml        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| namf        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nams        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| namt        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(1023) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The values are never null but many, sometimes the vast majority, are empty strings.

I am building the name column. The obvious way to do this is:

concat(namt, ' ', namf, ' ', naml, ' ', nams)

But when 2 or 3 of those are blank that gives me a lot of double-spaces and space padding at the beginning or end of the string.

Things I have done:

1) use python regex's to find and remove the extra spaces. This works if I have a month or so for it to run.

2) put the name together as above and use SQL to find and replace the extra spaces. Again, takes a really long time.

One of the problems is that the MySQL library for python has a cursor especially set up for dealing with large result sets. There is nothing similar for large query operations. Or perhaps I am looking at this wrong.

```
% pip freeze
...
MySQL-python==1.2.5c
...
```

3) Pull the names out into a tab-separated text file and do the fixing there, and then load the file into to the new table. Blech. Lots of dumb scripting. Use sed or awk? What?

4) I can do the concat() operations in 15 different queries and I do the proper concat for each so that I do not have extra spaces in the name. I have:

1. namt = null and namf = null and naml = null and nams != null (case 0001)
2. namt = null and namf = null and naml != null and nams = null (case 0010)
3. namt = null and namf = null and naml != null and nams != null (case 0011)
4. etc, etc.

This is actually what I went with. It takes less than a day to run. Woohoo!

But I am doing similar things for other reasons too and how the heck many times do I want to write this kind of code? Ick!

There must be a smarter way to do this that I am not seeing. I am doing this in about 2 dozen tables, with 2 - 5 names in each table, with sometimes around 15,000 rows and sometimes 20,000,000 rows. Most tables are in the 300,000 to 750,000 range. And, jeez, am I tired....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, I think you are looking for `concat_ws()`:

```
concat_ws(' ', nullif(namt, ''), nullif(namf, ''), nullif(naml, ''), nullif(nams, ''))
```

The `nullif()` turns the value to `NULL` if it is blank.  `concat_ws()` ignores `NULL` values, so you won't get duplicated spaces.

Comment: Query OK, 199425 rows affected (13 min 53.12 sec)
Rows matched: 19898385  Changed: 199425  Warnings: 0